# Urllib html not showing

Tags: regex, python-3.x, request, urllib

When I use the Urllib module, I can call/print/search the html of a website the first time, but when I try again it is gone.  How can I keep the html throughout the program.

For example, when I try:

---

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.bing.com/search?q=Mike&go=&qs=n&form=QBLH&filt=all&pq=mike&sc=8-2&sp=-1&sk=')
search = re.findall(r'Mike',str(html.read()))

search
```

---

I get:

['Mike','Mike','Mike','Mike']

---

But then when I try to do this a second time like so:

```
results = re.findall(r'Mike',str(html.read()))
```

---

I get:

```
[]
```

when calling 'result'.

Why is this and how can I stop it from happening/fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without being very well versed in python, I'm guessing `html.read()` reads the http stream, so when you call it the second time there is nothing to read.

Try:

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.bing.com/search?q=Mike&go=&qs=n&form=QBLH&filt=all&pq=mike&sc=8-2&sp=-1&sk=')
data = str(html.read())
search = re.findall(r'Mike',data)
search
```

And then use

```
results = re.findall(r'Mike',data)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the correct guess of @rvalik that you can only read a stream once, `data = str(html.read())` is incorrect.  `urlopen` returns a `bytes` object and `str` returns the display representation of that object.  An example:

```
>>> data = b'Mike'
>>> str(data)
"b'Mike'"
```

What you should do is either decode the `bytes` object using the encoding of the HTML page (UTF-8 in this case):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

with urlopen('http://www.bing.com/search?q=Mike&go=&qs=n&form=QBLH&filt=all&pq=mike&sc=8-2&sp=-1&sk=') as html:
    data = html.read().decode('utf8')

print(re.findall(r'Mike',data))
```

or search with a bytes object:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

with urlopen('http://www.bing.com/search?q=Mike&go=&qs=n&form=QBLH&filt=all&pq=mike&sc=8-2&sp=-1&sk=') as html:
    data = html.read()

print(re.findall(rb'Mike',data))
```